VirtualBox on 22.04 LTS - has something changed between kernel 5.15.0-113-generic and 5.15.0-116-generic?
After a normal Ubuntu kernel upgrade of a VM server from 5.15.0-113-generic to 5.15.0-116-generic and a reboot, guest virtual machines don't start any more - a "guru meditation" error is displayed.  In the logs, after various dump info:
00:00:04.260021 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'GURU_MEDITATION'

After a force shutdown and the VM server off 5.15.0-113-generic, everything starts as normal.
The VirtualBox version is 6.1.50_Ubuntur161033.

Launchpad for this new issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2073267

Does someone know how to get the developer's attention to that bug/regression-update..?

@LUser the launchpad entry has lots of current discussions on it, so the bug is still working its way through the sausage machine (see especially https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/2073267/comments/17 ).

I wonder which information is missing. It is clear that this is a regression from working kernel (version 5.15.0-113-generic and earlier) to no longer working versions (including the current 5.15.0-117-generic). Seeing that the proposed version 5.15.0-118 has the same issue, I am afraid that this issue will not be addressed in the foreseeable future unless it is addressed in upstream. Perhaps no one really cares, as main development is on the kernel branch 6.8 (as in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)..?

(for anyone not following the launchpad issue) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2073267/comments/83 "The updated kernel should be available in ~2 weeks."

The 5.15.0-119-generic kernel (distributed to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS / Jammy by default) fixes this for me.  Hurrah!

I encountered the same issue on Xubuntu (XFCE Ubuntu) 22.04.4 LTS. Here are some workarounds I tried and their results:

I updated to VirtualBox 7.0 from the Oracle repositories. This worked on Kernel 5.15.0-116-generic, but the guest VMs experienced issues such as freezing, even after updating the guest additions and eventually removing them. So, I reverted to VirtualBox 6.1.50-161033 and Kernel 5.15.0-113-generic.

I waited for the update to Kernel 5.15.0-117-generic, but as LUser mentioned, the problem persisted with VirtualBox 6.1.50-161033.

Finally, I switched to Kernel 6.5.0. In the past, I had issues with 6.5.0, which is why I switched to 5.15.0. However, it is currently working fine, including VirtualBox 6.1.50-161033 and guest machines.


To switch to the Kernel 6.5.0, just install this meta-package from the Ubuntu repositories: linux-oem-22.04 (Complete OEM Linux kernel and headers). In my case, I also installed linux-tools-oem-22.04 (OEM Linux kernel tools), but I think this might not be necessary for VirtualBox 6.1.50-161033 to work.

kernel 5.15.0-117-generic ubuntu 22.04 VBox 7.0.20 and guest OS works fine
