Guru Meditation on Virtualbox
My host machine is Ubuntu and I have different guest machines in Virualbox. Up until yesterday, all of them (windows and ubuntu guests) were working fine. Today, all of them upon start will face this error:

A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped.


Increasing memory does not help. Playing with CPU options also does not help. Rebooting the host machine also does not help.
Virtualbox version: 6.1.50_Ubuntu r161033
Ubuntu host version: 20.04 focal
The log file is too big. Its ending is as follows:
end of log around before clicking on OK:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:00:03.361140 !!
00:00:03.361140 !! {vmsvga}
00:00:03.361140 !!
00:00:03.361140 Extension enabled:  false
00:00:03.361141 Configured:         false
00:00:03.361141 Base I/O port:      0xd010
00:00:03.361142 FIFO address:       00000000f0000000
00:00:03.361142 FIFO size:          2097152 (0x200000)
00:00:03.361142 FIFO external cmd:  0x0
00:00:03.361143 FIFO extcmd wakeup: 0
00:00:03.361143 FIFO min/max:       0/0
00:00:03.361143 Busy:               0x0
00:00:03.361143 Traces:             false (effective: true )
00:00:03.361144 Guest ID:           0x0 (0)
00:00:03.361144 IRQ status:         0x0
00:00:03.361144 IRQ mask:           0x0
00:00:03.361145 Pitch lock:         0x0 (FIFO:0x0)
00:00:03.361145 Current GMR ID:     0x0
00:00:03.361145 Capabilites reg:    0xf6c2a0
00:00:03.361145 Index reg:          0x0
00:00:03.361146 Action flags:       0x0
00:00:03.361146 Max display size:   5632x5632
00:00:03.361146 Display size:       4294967295x4294967295 4294967295bpp
00:00:03.361147 Scanline:           0 (0x0)
00:00:03.361147 Viewport position:  0x0
00:00:03.361147 Viewport size:      0x0
00:00:03.361147 Cursor active:      false
00:00:03.361148 Cursor hotspot:     0x0
00:00:03.361148 Cursor size:        0x0
00:00:03.361149 Cursor byte size:   0 (0x0)
00:00:03.361149 3D enabled:         false
00:00:03.361149 Driver mode:        720x400 32bpp
00:00:03.361150 Driver pitch:       2880 (0xb40)
00:00:03.361150 !!
00:00:03.361150 !! {vmsvga3dctx}
00:00:03.361151 !!
00:00:03.361152 !!
00:00:03.361152 !! {vmsvga3dsfc}
00:00:03.361152 !!
00:00:03.361152 !!
00:00:03.361152 !! {vmsvga3dsurf}
00:00:03.361153 !!
00:00:03.361153 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:03.361200 emR3Debug: rc=VERR_VMM_SET_JMP_ABORTED_RESUME
00:00:03.423841 GUI: Machine-window #0 deactivated
00:00:03.423874 GUI: Releasing mouse on focus out
00:00:03.423880 GUI: Releasing keyboard on focus out
00:00:03.425282 GUI: Machine-view #0 unfocused, reason=3
00:09:10.403673 GUI: User request to power VM off on Guru Meditation.
00:09:10.403700 GUI: Passing request to power VM off from machine-logic to UI session.
00:09:10.403706 GUI: Powering VM down on UI session power off request...
00:09:10.403866 Console: Machine state changed to 'Stopping'
00:09:10.404303 Console::powerDown(): A request to power off the VM has been issued (mMachineState=Stopping, InUninit=0)
00:09:10.404559 Changing the VM state from 'GURU_MEDITATION' to 'POWERING_OFF'
00:09:10.404574 ****************** Guest state at power off for VCpu 1 ******************

End of log after clicking on OK:
00:09:10.464817 E1000#0: Larger TX frames    : 0
00:09:10.464823 E1000#0: Max TX Delay        : 0
00:09:10.531519 GIM: KVM: Resetting MSRs
00:09:10.534960 Changing the VM state from 'DESTROYING' to 'TERMINATED'
00:09:10.534960 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:09:11.048662 GUI: Passing request to close Runtime UI from machine-logic to UI session.


I can provide more logs upon request.

The obvious question is, what changed? Did updates get installed on your pc?  I'm also running 20.04 but using VB 7 and it's working fine at the moment.

@OrganicMarble, I am aware of no change and no update. I only move my PC to a few meters away in the house. Without changing its devices. That's so strange. I believe I have used the same monitor connection too but let's give it 5% chance that I am wrong.

did you consider asking the question to the help community section listed in the graphic you pasted and what was the result?

@graham, no, I posted here only.

may be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1520766/virtualbox-on-22-04-lts-has-something-changed-between-kernel-5-15-0-113-generi

@FrancoisMarot, not sure if that is the same issue, also it has no conclusion.

Id be you I'd try to downgrade my kernel. Maybe your kernel was auto-updated by a security rule ?

Consider upgrading to VB 7.

@barej: I've exactly the same problem! Until few days ago my WinXP and Win10 guests was working perfectly. Today the error appears, it does not matter which guest I try to start. I did run the latest Ubuntu updates recently, but AFAIK there was no changes for VirtualBox. Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, VirtualBox 6.1.50_Ubuntu r161033

Sounds like this new bug associated with changes in the kernel: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2073267

I faced the same error for 3 VM-s.

A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped.

The issue started after upgrades of packages and kernels on Linux Mint.
Before that VM-s worked fine.
After upgrade of VB from 6.1.50 to 7 the problem went away.
I get the latest version from:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I cannot edit @DataScientYst's answer. I fixed the "VirtualBox Guru meditation" error in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS removing virtualbox packages dkms, qt, guest-utils and guest-additions as shown below:
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-qt
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-utils
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

I then downloaded the VirtualBox version 7.x DEB software package from VirtualBox-downloads and installed it with GDebi. The documentation suggests another method consisting of adding an apt source, and then install Virtualbox using:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-7.1

All virtual machines that had failed to start with version 6.x, could now be launched, although their original state was lost.
