Virtualbox error message "A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine" (running on Ubuntu 20 host)
I installed VirtualBox 6.1 to run Windows 10 as a guest OS which has no issues previously. I'm not sure if I had Windows 10 updated. I now getting the following message when I try to run the VM. Maybe I didn't enable the Nested VT-x/AMD-V, but it has been grayed out and I have no idea why.
Error message:

Nested VT-x/AMD-V:


This appears to be the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/q/1521244/243321. Looks like a bug has emerged with VB 6.1 on 20.04

The bug is not associated with VirtualBox, but is a regression in the linux kernel 5.15; see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2073267

I have LinuxMint 21 Vanessa (based on Ubuntu 22.04) on laptop with Intel i3-3110M processor. Virtualbox 6.1 was installed and worked well until linux kernel was updated from Linux 5.15.0-113 to Linux 5.15.0-118. And then "critical error occured". As it was proposed in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2073267

I deleted Virtual box:
sudo apt remove --purge virtualbox*
downloaded Virtual box-7.0 from [https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.20/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb]
and installed it:
sudo apt --fix-broken install virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb*
And 3 my VMs started to boot again. The problem only is to install/update GuestAdditions on every VM.


After I switched to another distribution of Linux to solve this problem, I discovered the problem was a kernel update pushed out by the Ubuntu upgrades was not compatible with Virtualbox 6.1.  The solution is to roll-back to a previous kernel version or to upgrade to Virtualbox 7 from the Virtualbox website as ver 6.1 is still the release in the Ubuntu 20.04 repository.
